# Выравнивание элементов с разным line-height

Tags: html, css

Взялся сверстать макет для практики. Опыт в верстке небольшой.
Возник вопрос по верстке меню навигации в `header`'е:
у элементов (логотип, список и контакты) по макету разный `line-height`. В результате по умолчанию они находятся на разной высоте строки.
Выровнял их при помощи свойства `align-items: baseline;`. Однако полагаю, что эта конструкция не слишком надежна - добавится новый элемент с другой высотой строки и всё поедет.
Подскажите, есть универсальный и надежный способ выравнивания элементов с разной высотой строки? Можно ли в данном случае сверстать по-другому?

Код:

```css
.main-navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding-top: 62px;
}

.main-header-logo {
  margin-right: 47px;
}

.site-navigation {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.site-navigation li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 44px;
}

.site-navigation li a {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 32.06px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2d2829;
}

.working-info {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: 'Circe', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 39.53px;
}
```

```html
<a class="main-header-logo">
  <img src="img/logo.png" width="67" height="18" alt="Логотип магазина Cakes">
</a>
<ul class="site-navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Наши торты</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="site-navigation-custom">Индивидуальный заказ</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Как заказать</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
<p class="working-info">+7 906 899 92 96</p>
```

[Ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/Zaurinio/0cp92umf/2/) на jsfiddle

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы разные элементы с разными `line-height` были на одном уровне?

Comment: Мне удалось выровнять их при помощи свойства align-items: baseline.
Хотел узнать, насколько это корректно и есть ли другие способы.

Comment: попробуйте `align-items: center;`